# How to resolve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am stuck one point.

I am getting this error from eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path
```

I tried few links and tried to solve problem, but I am unable to do so.

1. I changed Jar file location, no output
2. I also tried to change eclipse.ini, but it also couldn't resolve it.

What should I do?

If any other information or image is required regarding issue, I will provide. ask me in comments.

Thanks
Duaan

Comment: Add jogl to the library path.  More specifically, the error is telling you that a JNI module (not a Java class) is missing.  This is because you're using some JAR that contains classes with a "native" component, and so the native "alter egos" of the Java classes must be found.  These are accessed via the "library path", similar to the classpath but for non-Java modules.

Answer (score 0):

In your run configuration in Eclipse, add

```
-Djava.library.path=<path to JOGL>
```

under Arguments -> VM Arguments.

When you run outside of Eclipse, you'll need to make sure the native libraries are accessible too. As Hot Licks mentioned, these are the native libraries (e.g. dll files in Windows), not just the Java class files that come with JOGL.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with netbeans?